# What software is available for managing software licenses and hardware serial numbers?

Tags: licensing

I have to manage an increasing number of software licenses and hardware serial numbers across a growing company. To date this has been done using spreadsheets but this is a particularly inflexible solution.  Can any other IT managers out there suggest a software solution, ideally web-based, which will help me out?

Answer (score 3):

We use [GLPI](http://www.glpi-project.org/spip.php?lang=en) an [OCS Inventory](http://www.ocsinventory-ng.org/) to track almost all our hardware and software installs, the two softwares integrates one with each other very well. Also we use the incident tracking system provided by GLPI for all our remote branches assistance. Both of them are OpenSource and Web Based.

Comment: thumbs up for glpi.

Answer (score 1):

I use [system center configuration manager](http://www.microsoft.com/systemcenter/en/us/configuration-manager.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest: [spiceworks](http://www.spiceworks.com) - A great growing free service (if you don't mind the ads on the side panel).

I use it extensively, it has lots of addon written by users.